# Triggering a "Win" in a Vanilla JavaScript Hangman Game

Tags: javascript, function, random, return, counter

So I've already asked a few questions regarding this Hangman game (and have gotten awesome answers), but I've been continually tripped up by my "score keeper". The game almost does everything I need it too, but a "win" will not be logged until after a random key is pressed AFTER the entire word has been filled in...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hangman</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hangman!</h1>

    <p>
        <font size="+3"><span id="answer"></span></font>
    </p>
    <p>Lives: <span id="counter"></span></p>
    <p id="wrongGuesses"></p>
    <p>Wins: <span id="wins"></span></p>
    <p>Losses: <span id="losses"></span></p>


    <script type="text/javascript">

var word;

var guess;      //user guess
var letters = [];       //correctly guessed letters
var wrongLetters = [];      //incorrectly guessed letters
var counter;        //counts correct letters
var losses = 0;
var wins = 0;


document.getElementById("losses").innerHTML = losses;
document.getElementById("wins").innerHTML = wins;

var wordList = ["cat", "dog", "wolf", "laser", "apple"];        //FILL LIST LATER!!


//randomly chooses a word from the array and replaces letters with underscores
function start() {
    word = wordList[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordList.length)];
    counter = 7;
    document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = counter;
    for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        letters[i] = "__";
    }

    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = letters.join(" ");
    console.log(word);

}


//checks if letter is in the word or not
function checkLetter() {
    document.onkeyup = function(event) {
        guess = event.key.toLowerCase();
        //var found = false;
        for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
            if (guess === word[i]) {
                letters[i] = guess;
                document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = letters.join(" ");
                //found = true;
            } 
        }
        //wrong letters go into the wrongLetters array and are displayed
        //if (found) return;
        if (wrongLetters.indexOf(guess) < 0) {
            wrongLetters.push(guess);
            document.getElementById("wrongGuesses").innerHTML = wrongLetters.join(" ");
            //every wrong guess subtracts one from the counter
            counter--;
            console.log(counter);
            document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = counter;
            //when counter reaches 0 it's Game Over
            //+1 to the losses if 7 words are missed

            if (counter > 0 && letters.join("") === word) {             //THE ISSUE
                document.getElementById("wins").innerHTML = wins + 1;
                console.log(wins);
                confirm("YOU WIN! Play Again?");
                    wins++;
                    counter = 7;
                    letters = [ ];
                    wrongLetters = [ ];
                start();
            }

            else if (counter === 0) {
                document.getElementById("losses").innerHTML = losses + 1;
                console.log(losses);
                confirm("YOU LOOSE... play again?"); {
                    losses++;
                    counter = 7;
                    letters = [];
                    wrongLetters = [];
                    start();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


start();
checkLetter();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's what I have so far and here is a jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/t57zfv3t/11/ 
I know the main issue is with the found bool and the return, but I can't seem to find a way to work around it. If anyone has any insight it would be greatly appreciated and I apologize in advanced to anyone who I have already bothered with this. THANKS!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return if the letter is found even if it's a whole word match, so just check that in the condition too

```
//wrong letters go into the wrongLetters array and are displayed
if (found && letters.join("") !== word) return;
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! when I doing this almost has the opposite affect... when you guess the last letter it goes straight to the "win" alert without displaying that letter. That's definitely the closest I've had it to working properly, but it would be awesome if I could display that last letter before/during the win phase.

Comment: @michael-wolfe Ah, I made some changes here: https://jsfiddle.net/9L5epmyL/
The DOM didn't get time to update before the success message showed. Might be the same issue if you lose.

Comment: Wow that looks and functions great! Thanks for all your help!